# Formatando data e hora com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou consumindo dados de uma `API` e gostaria de saber como faço para passar o seguinte valor de data e hora, para o padrão brasileiro.

O formato retornado é esse:

```
2017-01-05T14:35:17.437
```

mas eu gostaria que fosse exibido

```
05-01-2017
```

Comment: Nesse específico formato, você vai ter que pegar o resultado, transformar um objeto Date do javascript, pegar os valores que deseja (dia, mês e ano) e formar uma nova _string_. Caso queira um jeito mais fácil, é só pegar esse valor, transformar em um objeto Date do javascript e posteriormente utilizar o método `toLocaleString()`, que irá retornar nesse formato: dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) que faz todo trabalho de *formatação de data*, *cálculos*, ***etc***:

```js
moment.locale('pt-br');
console.log(moment('2017-01-05T14:35:17.437').format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

mas, também pode ser feito com o puro [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```js
var data = '2017-01-05T14:35:17.437';
var parte = data.substring(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(parte);
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [momentjs - Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.](http://momentjs.com/)
- [JavaScript String substring() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)
- [JavaScript String split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [JavaScript Array reverse() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)
- [JavaScript Array join() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: Obrigado a ajuda de todos : )

Answer (score 2):

Só veja como transformar em string essa sua data e teste isso:

Ex:

```
var formatoCompleto = "2017-01-05T14:35:17.437";
var dataFormatada = formatoCompleto.substring(0,formatoCompleto.indexOf("T"));
var dadosData = dataFormatada.split("-");

var dataFinal = dadosData[2]+"-"+dadosData[1]+"-"+dadosData[0];
console.log(dataFinal);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda : )